# How do you tell if your Chrome Packaged App is in development mode or unpacked?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I'd like to automatically switch out some settings for development and production, so how do I tell if I'm running an unpacked version?

Answer (score 0):

Either build that information into your product at build time (much as you would to distinguish a debug build from a release build for compiled code), or use a heuristic. Here are some ideas:

- If the extension ID is not the store version ID, you're probably unpacked.
- If chrome.runtime.getManifest doesn't have a `key` value, then you know the store didn't package it.

Comment: Example of build-time: https://github.com/sowbug/happynine/blob/master/build_official

Comment: I thought about the key but I have mine hard coded so I can use the identity API.